# Show that the natural map between vectors and linear functions on $\mathbb R^n$ is bijective

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I'm doing this problem in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds and I need help with what the second statement is trying to say and how it is proven.

> *Let $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ denote the dual space of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ . If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define $\varphi_x \in (\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ by $\varphi_x(y) =\langle x,y\rangle$.  Define $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ by $T(x) = \varphi_x$. Show that $T$ is a $1 - 1$ linear transformation and **conclude that every $\varphi$ $\in$ $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ is $\varphi_{x}$ for a unique $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.**

I understand how to do the first part in proving that T is a linear transformation, but the second statement confuses me even when I look at the proof. I know this may be trivial, but I would appreciate any help in clarifying what the statement is trying to say as well as why its proved by showing that  $\varphi_{ax + by}$ = $a\varphi_{x} + b\varphi{y}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since $\mathbb R^n$ is $n$-dimensional, $\left(\mathbb R^n\right)^*$ is also $n$-dimensional. To show $T$ is invertible it therefore suffices to show $T$ has trivial kernel.

To this end, let $x\in\ker T$. Then $T(x)(y)=0$ whenever $y\in\mathbb R^n$. That is, $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ whenever $y\in\mathbb R^n$. In particular, $\langle x,e_i\rangle=0$ for each of the standard basis vectors $e_1,\dotsc,e_n\in\mathbb R^n$. But now this implies $x_i=0$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ so $x=\mathbf 0$. Hence $T$ has trivial kernel.

Comment: Nice and clear explanation, I understand it now, it just clicked for me!